# Error in gem websocket-driver 0.7.5 when running rails new Appname --api (MACOS CATALINA ENVIROMENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

Everything was working fine but when I wanted to start a new api with
rails new Appname --api

I got this error. All my environment in my computer never change (no update ran before)

**Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

**An error occurred while installing websocket-driver (0.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install websocket-driver -v '0.7.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.**

My rails is Rails 6.1.3.2
All the info I found about the error is for windows, but I am not using windows.
I will appreciate help.
Thank you.